# Solve this by using Fermat's little theorem: $x=3^{10} \text{ mod } 11$ in $Z_{11}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> Solve this by using Fermat's little theorem: $x=3^{10} \text{ mod }
> 11$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

We know(?) that if $$a=b \text{ mod }c$$

then we also have that

$$a^{n}=b^{n} \text{ mod }c$$

so

$$x=3^{10} \text{ mod }11 \Leftrightarrow x^{10}=3^{10}\text{ mod }11$$

But that doesn't really help me.. Or I used fermat wrong here?

Comment: Can you state Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: Oh I think the 10's supposed to be 11`?
$$a^{n} = a \text{ mod }n$$?

Comment: Can you state Fermat's little theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fermat's Little Theorem, as $(3,11) = 1$ we have that $3^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$, so basically you're solving $x \equiv 3^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$. This means that the solution is $[1]_{11}$, i.e. the residue class of 1 modulo 11.

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you mean by "residue"? Just the solution of $1 \text{ mod }11$, right?

Comment: The residue class of $1$ modulo $11$ are the numbers that give residue of $1$ when divided by $1$. In other words $[1]_{11} = \{1,12,23,34,...\}$